# storefront design changes

Tags: magento2, frontend, design

I've run the following commands as I've added a new module:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-contet:deploy
```

after running those commands I've some issues with admin panel, So I run `static-deploy` command but with `ar_SA` language.

since then I notice a part of website (widget) appear and disappear without changing the design.

what are causes of that

Answer (score 0):

First it's `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and not `php bin/magento setup:static-contet:deploy`

- Clean the **content** of : `var/view_preprocessed/`, `pub/static/`
- Then deploy the **static-content** : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`